# ASP.Net Fill Grid with data from DataTable OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem when I am trying to get data into a gridview in my ASP.NET application.

This is the back end code of my aspx (I apologize for the horrible indenting, I still need to experiment more with stackoverflow code)

```
    using System;
    using DBComponentsLibrary;
    using DBComponentsLibrary.NameEventDataSetTableAdapters;

    namespace NameEvents
    {

public partial class TestWebFormView : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
    {
                //GC.Collect();
                //SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder();
                NameTableAdapter TA = new NameTableAdapter();
                NameDataSet rds = new NameDataSet();
                NameDataSet.NameDataTable Rdt = new NameDataSet.NameDataTable();
                TA.Fill(Rdt);
                GridView.DataSource = Rdt;
                GridView.DataBind();
                GridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Visible = true;
                int i = 2;                    
                //TA.GetData();
               }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

And this is my aspx div container holding the gridview

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" visible="true" >

        <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10, Column11, Column12, Column13,"></asp:GridView>
</div>

    <%--x = Parameter names in the table--%>
</form>
```

Results in:

```
    $exception  {"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."} System.OutOfMemoryException
```

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more code and explain exactly what it is you are doing and what data you are trying to display. However, make sure you are disposing the objects that need to be disposed.

Comment: Please be more specific of what you need so i can provide it Edit: The point of the application is to do a Event Log from a relational database into a ASP.Net Application. The size of the DB is currently around 30-40000 rows

Comment: well for one thing the code your provided won't compile - it's not complete. The curly braces indicate that it is either a method on it's own, or a loop, but I can't tell.

Comment: wait - are you trying to select 40,000 rows in a single query and then display them on one page for a user?

Comment: I am using .xsd component.

Comment: I don't think that means you can get away with trying to do a select on 40,000 rows and then try to render them on a single page. You need to reduce the amount of rows you are selecting at a single time in order to stop your server having a heart attack. Use pagination.

Comment: Is adding property AllowPaging="true" to the GridView sufficient?

Comment: As well as that, you need to modify your query to reduce the number of results being retrieved by your `Page_Load` to something more manageable. Say, 100 results at a time. Not only to avoid the out of memory exception, but also - really, what good does it do to show a human 40,000 rows at a time?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                DataBind();
                loadGridData();
        }
```

LoadGridData(); is a method that holds the instancing of my TableDataAdapter, Dataset and DataTable. Currently slows down the application since everytime a action is performed everything gets instanced again as the page loads up. Working on a solution to solve it with putting either the dataset or dtable into a session

Code for loadGridData();

```
{
            NameTableAdapter TA = new  NameTableAdapter();
            NameDataSet rds = new NameDataSet();
            NameDataSet.NameDataTable Rdt = new NameDataSet.NameDataTable();
            TA.Fill(Rdt);
            GridView.DataSource = Rdt;
            GridView.DataBind();
            GridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Visible = true;
        }
```